# cookiecutter error in django

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I installed a cookie cutter using pip.

Then I ran this $ [cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)

But this doesn't work.

This is the traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/choco/.local/bin/cookiecutter", line 7, in
 from cookiecutter.main import main
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cookiecutter'
```

Comment: what's your python version? Are you using virtual environment? Double check that cookiecutter is installed in your project python path by `pip freeze`

Comment: my python version is 3.6 and I'm using virtual enviroment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using the following steps:

- Move to the folder where the virtual environment is installed
- started the virtual environment (Activate it)
- Install the cookiecutter using Pip

The problem is installing the module outside the virtualenv.

Comment: This is the file path. Is there a problem here?
./.local/bin/cookiecutter
./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cookiecutter

Comment: No. Your file name seems to cause problem. can you change your file name to something else and run?

Comment: Because your file name and module names are same.

Comment: I have never created a file named cookiecutter
Does it mean to rename cookiecutter module?

Comment: No. I guess I have mistaken. Pardon.

Comment: That means you haven't installed it. just try "pip install cookiecutter"

Comment: ah I run it into a virtual environment and it did not respond

Comment: Name: cookiecutter
Version: 1.6.0
Summary: A command-line utility that creates projects from project templates, e.g. creating a Python package project from a Python package project template.
Home-page: https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter
Author: Audrey Roy
Author-email: audreyr@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/choco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: whichcraft, poyo, binaryornot, click, jinja2, future, requests, jinja2-time
Required-by:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174214/discussion-between-mufeed-and-choco).

Answer (score 0):

Is Anaconda installed in your development environment ?

If so, there may be problems between your two installations.

the command to install cookiecutter with conda is :

```
conda install -c conda-forge cookiecutter
```